# How to test process.on() using mocha?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

Apologies if this is a naive question. I'm relatively new to Typescript and Mocha testing. I have the following processes which I want to test to increase code coverage:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    LoggingService.error(reason, 'unhandledRejection', 'Unhandled Rejection at:');
});

process.on('uncaughtException', (error) => {
    LoggingService.error(error, 'unhandledRejection', 'Caught exception: ');
});

process.on('warning', (warning) => {
    LoggingService.info('Warning, Message: ' + warning.message + ' Stack: ' + warning.stack, 'warning');
});

process.on('exit', (code) => {
    LoggingService.error(null, 'NodeJs Exit', `Node.js process is about to exit with code: ${code}`);
});
```

How do I write tests in mocha for processes? In particular, if I want to simulate `process.on` for `unhandledRejection, uncaughtException, warning, exit` how would I be able to do that and what would I be expecting since there's no `return` statement for these processes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can emit events on `process` object to test the event handlers.
And you can spy on `LoggingService` object to check that methods are invoked with the expected arguments using a library like [sinon](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon).

This `console.log` based example shows the idea:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');

// This event handler is what we are going to test 
process.on('warning', () => {
  console.log('received warning');
});

describe('process', () => {
  it('should handle "warning" event', (done) => {
    const spy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');

    process.on('warning', () => {
      sinon.assert.calledWith(spy, 'received warning')
      done()
    });

    process.emit('warning')
  })
})
```

Comment: I'm not able to test it. It says `Argument of type '"warning"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"disconnect"'.ts(2345)`. FYI: I'm using Hapi.js and typescript to build the rest API.

Comment: I resolved the above issue, But not working for `uncaughtException`. It fails the unit test case `process.emit("uncaughtException", new Error("raise error"));`